# conversion failed when converting nvarchar to int

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am getting above error can anyone please help what is the issue with the code...

```
P.YKey BETWEEN YEAR('''+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @BDate, 103) +''') 
           AND YEAR('''+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @eDate, 103) +''')
   AND P.DCreation BETWEEN '''+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @BDate, 103) +''' 
                       AND '''+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @eDate, 103) +''''
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of @BDate, @eDate?

Update:
As the type of the two variables are DATETIME, the conversion is not necessary.

```
P.YKey BETWEEN YEAR(@BDate) 
           AND YEAR(@eDate)
   AND P.DCreation BETWEEN @BDate 
                       AND @eDate
```

Answer (score 0):

as it seems that you are interested on the creation date only, not the time, I would also cast the datetimes to date. So assuming that DCreation is datetime too:

```
P.YKey BETWEEN YEAR(@BDate) 
           AND YEAR(@eDate)
   AND cast(P.DCreation as date) BETWEEN cast(@BDate as date) 
                                 AND cast(@eDate as date)
```